# Pizza order system Hashmaps and general syntax

Tags: java

straight to the point with this one. I just need some general guidance on whether the program i've written will actually work correctly with Hashmaps and just my approach to trying to complete tasks in general.(ive tried compiling it and it throws an error with line 90 regarding the else statement, think my brackets are messed up)

The purpose of the first function is to have the user input an order of upto 5 characters in one line(havent written anything to check this yet), the first character must be M or L for medium or large pizza. Its then followed by 0 to 4 characters for the toppings.

the second function purpose is the same as the first, only it shoudnt allow  3 or more of the same toppings.

```
public class Exercise_1{
    public static void pizzaServiceA(String args[]){

        HashMap <Character, String> Toppings = new Hashmap <Character, String>();

        //pizza
        dictionary.put("m", "meduim");
        dictionary.put("l", "large");

        //topping
        dictionary.put("h", "ham");
        dictionary.put("m", "mozzerella");
        dictionary.put("o", "olives");
        dictionary.put("p", "pineapple");
        dictionary.put("s", "spinach");

        dictionary.put("H", "ham");
        dictionary.put("M", "mozzerella");
        dictionary.put("O", "olives");
        dictionary.put("P", "pineapple");
        dictionary.put("S", "spinach");

        HashMap <Character, Double> Prices = new Hashmap <Character, Double>();


        //pizza price 
        dictionary.put("m", 4.00);
        dictionary.put("l", 5.00);

        //topping price medium
        dictionary.put("h", 1.40);
        dictionary.put("m", 1.00);
        dictionary.put("o", 0.80);
        dictionary.put("p", 1.00);
        dictionary.put("s", 1.20);

        //topping price large
        dictionary.put("H", 2.10);
        dictionary.put("M", 1.50);
        dictionary.put("O", 1.20);
        dictionary.put("P", 1.50);
        dictionary.put("S", 1.20);


        System.out.println("Enter a pizza order: ");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String orders = reader.nextLine();
        Char[] orderLetters = orders.toCharArray();


        String fullOrder = "";
        Double fullPrice = 0.0;


        //check if sequence enters it more than 5 characters

        if (input.equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println("Quitting.");
                System.exit(0);
            } 

        else if (!(order[0].equals('l')))
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the size of your pizza, m or l");

        }

        else if (!(order[0].equals('m')))
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the size of your pizza, m or l");
        }


        for(Char orderLetters : c.toCharArray())
        {
            Double price = Prices.get(orderLetters);
            fullPrice += price;

            String type = Toppings.get(orderLetters);
            if(type == 'm' || type == 'l')
            {
                fullOrder += type + " pizza with ";
            }
            else
            {
                fullOrder += type + ",";
            }


        }
        fullOrder += fullPrice;
        System.out.printf("%.2f", "£", fullOrder);

    }
    public static void pizzaServiceB(){
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new Hashmap<Character, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i <s.length(); i++){
            char orderLetters = c.charAt(i); //s.charAt?
            if (map.containsKey(orderLetters)){
                int c = map.get(orderLetters); //counts letters in orderletters
                map.put(orderLetters, ++c);
                {
                    else 
                    {
                        map.put(orderLetters, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (c.equals() = 3){
            System.out.println("You cannot order "); //if topping occurs 3 times print
        }

        //same functionality of A but orders with more than 3 toppings shoudlnt be allowed
    }



    public static void main(){
        Exercise_1 ex1 = null;
        ex1.testpizzaServiceA();
        //ex1.testpizzaServiceB();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `dictionary`?

Comment: Also, it seems like you're trying to pass a `String` to `put()`, when it is expecting a `Character`. I would double check the creation of your `HashMap` objects.

Comment: yeh i completely overlooked this. I was using a dictionary instead of hashmaps before and forgot to change how i was adding the strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using a `HashMap` to map characters to all your information. You could, for instance, create a `Pizza` class where you can set up the pizza (determine the size and add the toppings). A list of topping could be `List<Topping>`, where `Topping` is an enum.

```
class Pizza {

    public static enum Topping {
        HAM, MOZZARELLA, OLIVES, PINEAPPLE, SPINACH,
        CHEESE; // I added cheese. I love cheese.
    }

    public static enum Size {
        MEDIUM, LARGE;
    }

    private List<Topping> toppings = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTopping(Topping topping) {
        // First, test if the list with toppings does not contain
        // the given topping more than once.
        this.toppings.add(topping);
    }
}
```

**Storing the prices**
And then you need to somehow save the prices somewhere, for instance, in a `HashMap`. But you can also define a price property in the `Topping` class if you want to. Assuming each combination between the pizza size and each topping must have its own price, you should maintain a list somewhere – perhaps a `HashMap` – and make sure all combinations are present in the list. If not, then the consumer might have it for free. :-)

**Processing the input**
To process the input from the `Scanner`, you can just make two methods, one for defining the pizza size, and one for defining the toppings. These should not be in your pizza class.

```
private void consumeSizeToken(char token) {
    // Obtain the pizza object somewhere, otherwise add it to the
    // method's parameter list.
    switch (token) {
        case 'm':
            // I assume the Pizza class to have a setSize() method.
            pizza.setSize(Size.MEDIUM);
            break;
        case 'l':
            pizza.setSize(Size.LARGE);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid pizza size");
    }
}

private void consumeToppingToken(char token) {
    // Do the same as the consumeSizeToken() method, but, of course,
    // handle the toppings.
}
```

In order process the input, just assume the first character is the size, and the remaining characters are toppings:

```
consumeSizeToken(input.charAt(0));
for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
    consumeToppingToken(input.charAt(i);
}
```

---

You should also take this into consideration:

- Variable names, other than *constants*, should **always** start with a lowercase letter.
- Since Java 7, you can use the *diamond operator*. If you define a reference to a generic type, you can omit the generic parameters for constructors of generic classes, because they can be inferred. For example `HashMap<Character, String> toppings = new Hashmap<Character, String>()` can be replaced by `HashMap<Character, String> toppings = new Hashmap<>()`.
- Floating point arithmetic should not be used for monetary values. Replace it with int, counting the cents. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed responce, ill try rewriting using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are unique in `HashMap` so when you are trying to put two value in same key last added value override contents .

in your code you have use key `m` two times to put values for Pizza and topping in same `HashMap` Object dictionary.

//pizza

```
dictionary.put("m", "meduim");
```

//topping

```
dictionary.put("m", "mozzerella");
```

Comment: should i add another hashmap just for the pizza sizes in that case?

Comment: yes you can but if you want to persist in only one `HashMap` then you need to use different keys for each entry.